# if $g(x)=\int_3^{x^4}t\sqrt{2+t}dt$ then what is $g'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is not my homework I am just getting nervous for my test

if 
$$
g(x)=\int_3^{x^4}t\sqrt{2+t}dt
$$
what is $g'(x)$?

and

consider 
$$
g(x) = \int_0^x (t^2-4)e^{t^2}dt.
$$
Find all $x$ values where $g(x)$ has a local maximum

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If you have $$g(x)=\int_a^{x}f(t)\,dt,$$then$$g'(x)=f(x).$$Now use the chain rule, and you find the answer to the first question. Apply the same technique for the second one, but find the zeroes of the function and check whether they're maxima or minima.

Comment: can you explan a little more on the first one pleasee or give me another example?

Comment: Your integral is the same as $g\circ h(x)$ where $h(x)=x^4$. Now use the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

We're given $g(x) = \displaystyle\int_{3}^{x^4} t\sqrt{2+t} dt.$ To find $g^{\prime}(x),$ you need to apply the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus. Essentially, if $F(t)$ is the antiderivative of $t\sqrt{2+t},$ then you know $g(x) = F(x^4) - F(3),$ from which $g^{\prime}(x) = 4x^3 F^{\prime}(x^4) = 4x^3 \cdot x^4\sqrt{2+x^4}.$

For the second question, $g^{\prime}(x) = (x^2 - 4)e^{x^2} = 0 \iff x = \pm 2.$ To check whether a critical point is a local max, min, or inflection point, apply the second derivative test. Then $g^{\prime\prime}(x) = 2xe^{x^2} + 2x^3e^{x^2} - 8xe^{x^2},$ so $g^{\prime\prime}(2) = 4e^4 > 0$ and $g^{\prime\prime}(-2) = -4e^{4} < 0,$ whence $g(-2)$ is a local max.

Comment: The derivative is $(x^2-4)e^{x^2}$. This is positive for $x\lt -2$, negative for $-2\lt x\lt 2$, then positive for $x\gt 2$. So our function is increasing until $x-2$, then decreasing until $x=2$, then increasing. So there is a local max at $x=-2$ and a local min at $x=2$. Often students find this kind of analysis safer than the second derivative test. For one thing, it is all too easy to compute the second derivative incorrectly.

Comment: This is true, but the second derivative test has a nice generalization to higher dimensions while this sort of analysis won't work anymore.

Comment: Agreed. I wrote my remark for the context of teaching a first calculus course.